# pointer problem of circuit doubly LinkedList in C

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

Error was happend in `main` at bottom.

> Add Node - data : 1 
>  Segmentation fault (core dumped)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

typedef struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node* prev;
    struct Node* next;
}Node;

typedef struct List
{
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;
    int count;
}List;
```

```
void InitList(List *list)
{
    (list) = (List*)malloc(sizeof(List));
    (list) -> head = NULL;
    (list) -> tail = NULL;
    (list) -> count = 0;
}
```

```
Node* CreateNode(int data)
{
    Node* node = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    node -> data = data;
    node -> prev = NULL;
    node -> next = NULL;
    return node;
}
```

```
void AddNode(List *list, Node* node)
{
    if (!(list) || !node) return;
    printf("Add Node - data : %d\n", node -> data);

    if ((list) -> count == 0)
    {
        (list) -> head = (list) -> tail = node;
        node -> next = node -> prev = node;
    }
    else
    {
        node -> prev = (list) -> tail;
        node -> next = node -> prev = node;
        
        (list) -> tail -> next = node;
        (list) -> head -> prev = node;
        (list) -> tail = node;
    }

    (list) -> count++;
}
```

```
int main()
{
    List list;
    InitList(&list);
    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) 
        AddNode(&list, CreateNode(i));

    return 0;
}
```

This is a code about circuit doubly LinkedList in C. There was exist original code and I revised that to know why at original multiple pointer was used. Error happened directly when `AddNode(&list, CreateNode(i)` was called in main.

(this was the site of the original code but not english)
(https://huiyu.tistory.com/entry/%EC%9E%90%EB%A3%8C%EA%B5%AC%EC%A1%B0-%EB%8F%99%EC%A0%81%ED%95%A0%EB%8B%B9%EC%9D%84-%EC%9D%B4%EC%9A%A9%ED%95%9C-%EC%97%B0%EA%B2%B0-%EB%A6%AC%EC%8A%A4%ED%8A%B8Linked-List-%EA%B5%AC%ED%98%84)

I expected that It'll be working because in `main`, I declared `List list` and then call `InitList(&list)`. I thought it was *call-by-reference* but it didn't maybe.

I tried some tests, then I found tsomething.

1. I call the `InitList` with address of list typed List.
2. I expected that list would be initialized because I gave argument with address.
3. But when I printed the value of `count` of `list`, it was *garbage value*. (when I printed in `InitList`, that was 0)
4. So `count` was not zero while `head` and `tail` of list was `NULL`(found through `assert`), then Error happened.

I cannot understand why it was not *call-by-reference*, and why multiple pointers is needed.

Comment: Please try to reduce the amount of code. You have to identify which portion of the code gives you the problem you are facing. For further information please read how to provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

Remember that arguments to functions are passed *by value*. That means the values in the call is *copied* into the functions local argument variables. All the function have is a copy, which is independent of the original variable or value from the call. That means

```
(list) = (List*)malloc(sizeof(List));
```

in your `InitList` will simply not work, you only modify the local `list` variable. The original value `&list` from the `main` function will not be modified. And in fact it *cant*.

This means that the `List` structure object you initialize in the `InitList` function, is not the same as the one in the `main` function. The `List` structure object in the `main` function will remain uninitialized.

It seems you have heard that emulating pass by reference works by passing pointers to variables. But you miss an important point: The pointer itself will still be passed by value.

The simple solution to your problem is to simply drop that assignment from the `InitList` function:

```
void InitList(List *list)
{
    // list is already pointing to a properly allocated List structure
    (list) -> head = NULL;
    (list) -> tail = NULL;
    (list) -> count = 0;
}
```

Other alternatives is to change `list` in the `main` function to a pointer, and pass a pointer to that pointer, which means that `InitList` must take a `List **list` argument. *Or* you define `list` as a normal local variable, do the allocation, and then *return* the pointer.

Comment: Oh yeah I need to assign to "reference" of address even if local value and reference were equal values! Finally I understand why originally multiple pointers were used. a Single pointer is also possible and how it's possible logically. Thank you, sir.

Answer (score 0):

When you write List list; => memory is already allocated to list object now when you do malloc again inside the initlist() function then you point the pointer to a new memory location and hence this pointer which was earlier pointing to the location of list object is now pointing to some other address location. So all the changes that you made to this pointer in initlist functions are reflected to the struct object stored at some new address location (other than the list object).

Solution: Same as mentioned in other answers i.e. removing malloc line inside initlist function.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can leave mallock() inside InitList function, but then You just need to define 'list' variable as a pointer to List structure in main() function:

```
List *list = NULL;
```